# My keydown functions with numbers are doing very weird

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am doing keypress events, which works just fine for the spacebar but if I try to add numbers, 1, 2, 3 work fine but once I add 4 it completely starts doing weird, for example 4 triggers 3, 3 triggers 2, 2 triggers 1 or 4 triggers 2 and 3 triggers nothing and 2 triggers 1, I have been searching for the past hours.
I know my current code number combination is not right, but I have already tried 48,49,50,51

I have already tried replacing the classes with ids, doesn't work, I have also tried several different number combinations

```
$(window).keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.which === 32) {
        $("button").click();
    }
});
$(window).keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.which === 48) {
        $(".pokeball:nth-of-type(1)").click();
    }
});
$(window).keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.which === 49) {
        $(".pokeball:nth-of-type(2)").click();
    }
});
$(window).keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.which === 52) {
        $(".pokeball:nth-of-type(3)").click();
    }
});
$(window).keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.which === 50) {
        $(".pokeball:nth-of-type(4)").click();
```

my expectations are the keypress 48 to trigger with pressing 1, the trigger 49 with 2, the trigger 52 with 3 and the trigger 50 with 4! these numbers can be changed I just want the function to execute on pressing the key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may not need multiple `if` you can do it without using `if` and get the typed character and pass that value to the jquery selector

```
$(window).keypress(function(e) {
      let code = String.fromCharCode(e.which || e.keyCode);
      console.log(code)
      $(".pokeball:nth-of-type("+code +")").click();
    })
```